# How do you change udev rules without restarting (e.g. to change eth1 to eth0)?

Tags: networking, dhcp, udev, remastersys

**TLDR;** How do you apply changes to `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` without restarting? (See [this documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/network-configuration.html) about ethernet interface logical names.)

**Long version:**

I have a bootable USB flash drive running an image made by [remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/) of 11.04. I want to be able to use this bootable USB drive to run a DHCP server from any computer. To do this, I have to assign a static IP address to `eth0` in `/etc/network/interfaces` and reference `eth0` in `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`.

However, the network card is assigned ethX based on MAC address, so this only works on the first computer where the USB flash drive is used -- each subsequent computer's NIC will be assigned to `eth1`, `eth1`, etc.

It seems that there are two strategies that could work to solve this problem:

1. Dynamically rewrite `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` based on the first `ethX` that comes up when you run `ifconfig` -- this should be whatever NIC is actually in the computer.
2. Rewrite `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` so that whatever MAC address is assigned to the NIC is named `eth0`.

I know I can do #1 because changes to these files can be applied by restarting `networking` and `isc-dhcp-server`.

However, #2 seems cleaner to me as I believe the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` will build up a bunch of crud as this USB drive is used in different computers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with option #1 (dynamically rewriting the various config files that needed ethX). This was easy to do with a simple Ruby script.

If the script doing the dynamic rewrite is `startup.rb`, I created a wrapper called `startup-wrapper.rb` that calls the actual script with `exec 'sudo startup.rb'` so that `startup.rb` runs with root permissions.

I then created an entry in Startup Applications with the following command: `gnome-terminal -e /path/to/startup-wrapper.rb`. This will prompt the user for their password for the `sudo` on boot.